# Удаление файлов в директории Cron'ом

Tags: cron, inode

Есть платный виртуальный хостинг. У хостинга есть ограничение по использование ЦП.

Вопрос: Если я буду через `cron` выполнять удаление файлов в определенной директории, будет ли сильная нагрузка на процессор?

И еще вопрос про `inode`: При удаление файлов `иноды` остаются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. «сильно/не сильно» — это субъективная оценка. но процесс удаления файлов (опять же субъективно) вряд ли можно назвать серьёзной вычислительной задачей.
2. при удалении файлов inode-ы остаются и считаются «свободными».